# How to parse the file present on SDCArd

Tags: android

I have a file which I created and is present in data/data/com.andr.filedemo/files/a.xml.
Now I want to parse this file using XML Pull parser. How can we give the path of that file or how we can access that file and then parse that file using XML Pull parser.

Can anyone help me in sortig out this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**reading file from sdcard** :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779944/reading-a-specific-file-from-sdcard-in-android

**parsing xml file :** You can use below packages
 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
 //import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException.html;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

Comment: Thankyou. I want to how can we check in our application whether a particular file exists in data/data/com.stf.filedemo/files in this directory.

Comment: Here you can file exist                                            File yourFile = new File(getDir(null, 0), "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
yourFile.exists();