# Load images from sd card folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to load images from the specific folder in sd card.i saved images to folder in the sd card. now i want to load images from that folder.try to do this using online tutorials. but didn't work any thing.when i try to use below code i received blank screen.
What am I doing wrong? Many thanks for any help.

```
public class F6Activity extends softActivity
{
private Cursor cursor;
private int columnIndex;
Button next;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_f6);


Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
//request only the image ID to be returned
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
//Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
 cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  projection, 
  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
  new String[] {"%ereports%"},  
  null);
  //Get the column index of the image ID
  columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
  g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));



  }


 private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context context;

 public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) 
 {
  context = localContext;
 }

 public int getCount() 
 {
  return cursor.getCount();
 }
 public Object getItem(int position) 
 {
  return position;
 }
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ImageView i = new ImageView(context);
 // Move cursor to current position
 cursor.moveToPosition(position);
 // Get the current value for the requested column
 int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
 // obtain the image URI
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,      
 Integer.toString(imageID) );
 String url = uri.toString();
 // Set the content of the image based on the image URI
 int originalImageId = Integer.parseInt(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, 
 url.length()));
 Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),
                originalImageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
 i.setImageBitmap(b);
 i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
 i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
 int mGalleryItemBackground = 0;
i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

 return i;
 }
 }




 }
```

Comment: why you are calling setContentView method twice at beginning of onCreate mathod ?

Comment: Thank for your reply.i edited the code.i it must be setContentView(R.layout.activity_f6);. but still i received blank screen.

Comment: this question has been asked and answered 100 times over. Please search for relevant terms before posting your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading a specific file from sdcard in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779944/reading-a-specific-file-from-sdcard-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting confused with code, Now I can't say the problem in your code, it will take time for me. I suggest to use the code available at below link. It is working fine. I will try to find the problem in  your code afterwards. Now check the link below.

[Display images from SD card](http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard)