# How to read a CSV file from a SD card using Android

Tags: android

I am making a program and saving data to a CSV file in SD card.

Now I want to read that data from the CSV file as 10 separate variables and upload them to a Google spreadsheet. However I cannot read the file and get the data as 10 variables. All are String type data.

Comment: Need a little bit more information than just could not read the file. What is your code for reading the file? Is the filename a static in that it will never change, what kind of reader are you using to read the csv file? Need to see what you have tried before we can help you out.

Comment: You should add some code that you have written for it or else it'll be downvoted by others.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please provide more details regarding your problem.  Why can't you read the file?  What happens?  Do you get any error messages?  Posting a code snippet often helps others to understand your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the below link which has already been put up here, before some time.

Link is:

[reading a specific file from sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779944/reading-a-specific-file-from-sdcard-in-android)