# Download progress Bar absent in Notification when Downloading file inside Webview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, webview

I"m able to Download file from WebView but It doesn't show me the progress bar in Notification panel. But If I go to the Download directory of Ext storage, I can see the file.

How can make Download progress bar visible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code from library to initiate download

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        dm.enqueue(request);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

and my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateDialog"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".UpdateService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

</application>
```

Any help would be largely appreciated. And for the records , Download link are generated from Google drive

and my main activity file starts with:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean doubleBackToExitPressed = false;
private TextView textView;
private BottomBar bottomBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: On Which OS you are checking ? below Marshmallow or After it ?

Comment: I think your file is downloaded but you are unable to view that file is this the case ?

Comment: @FarazAhmed yes I noticed that , files are inside Download directory indeed. How should I solve it then. As I also have bluestacks emulater is 4.4.2 version and my device is also same version. But Download progress bar can be seen when I run in bluestacks and is absent if I run through my device.

Comment: @FarazAhmed I have edite my question. Thanks for pointing me in right Direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already file downloaded then get this file from SDCard or Downloaded directory.

1. [Read file from SDCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779944/reading-a-specific-file-from-sdcard-in-android)

Then open the file in default PDF viewer of the application see below

```
   public static void openPdfFileAsIntent(Context context, File file) {

    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Please add PDF Viewer Application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 openPdfFileAsIntent(MainActivity.this,file);
```

Comment: Well it is an alternative solution, but Is it not possible to view the Download progress bar just like when I download something from Default Browser. It would really help user to keep track of file , how long will it take to download it.

Comment: You can download a file by using custom downloader which publishes progress.